# Lower bound spectral radius of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, upper-lower-bounds, spectral-radius

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in (0, 1)$ such that $\alpha < \beta, \gamma < \beta$. Let $d \in \mathbb{N}, d \geq 4$.

I am interested in **bounding from below the spectral radius $\rho(K)$** of the following matrix $K$ of size $d$ (or even better determining it analytically).

$$K = \begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{(1 - \alpha)(1 - \gamma)} & \frac{\sqrt{\alpha \gamma}}{d-1} & \cdots & \cdots & \frac{\sqrt{\alpha \gamma}}{d-1} \\
\frac{\sqrt{\alpha \gamma}}{d-1} & \eta & \frac{\beta}{d-2}  & \cdots & \frac{\beta}{d-2} \\
\frac{\sqrt{\alpha \gamma}}{d-1} & \frac{\beta}{d-2} & \eta   & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \frac{\beta}{d-2}\\
\frac{\sqrt{\alpha \gamma}}{d-1} & \frac{\beta}{d-2} & \cdots & \frac{\beta}{d-2} & \eta \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $\eta = \sqrt{\left(1 - \beta - \frac{\alpha}{d-1}\right)\left((1 - \beta - \frac{\gamma}{d-1}\right)}$

Notice, as it can only help, that $K$ is symmetric, and has strictly positive entries. So far, have only been able to say that the spectral radius lies (up to reordering of the bounds) in

$$\left[ \sqrt{(1 - \alpha)(1 - \gamma)} + \sqrt{\alpha\gamma}; \frac{\sqrt{\alpha \gamma}}{d-1}+ \eta + \beta \right]$$

since by positivity $\rho(K)$ stands in between the minimum and maximum row sums.

Numerically, though, it seems that I have the following dependency $\rho(K) = 1 - O\left( \frac{f(\alpha, \gamma)}{d} \right)$, and this sort of dependency in $d$ is my goal, but I am a little bit short on tools to confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T,\ v=\frac1{\sqrt{d-1}}(0,1,\ldots,1)^T,\ p=\frac{\sqrt{\alpha\gamma}}{d-1},\ q=\frac\beta{d-2}$ and $r=\sqrt{(1-\alpha)(1-\gamma)}$. Then
$$
K=(r-\eta+q)uu^T+\sqrt{d-1}\,p(uv^T+vu^T)+(d-1)qvv^T+(\eta-q)I.
$$
So, $K-(\eta-q)I$ has rank $\le2$ and its restriction on $\operatorname{span}\{u,v\}$ has a matrix representation
$$
A=\pmatrix{r-\eta+q&\sqrt{d-1}\,p\\ \sqrt{d-1}\,p&(d-1)q}.
$$
When $d$ is large, $\eta-q>0$ and $A$ is entrywise positive. Hence
\begin{align}
\rho(K)
&=\eta-q+\rho(A)\\
&=\eta-q+
\frac{(r-\eta+dq)+\sqrt{\left[r-\eta-(d-2)q\right]^2+4(d-1)p^2}}{2}\\
&=\frac{(r+\eta+\beta)+\sqrt{(r-\eta-\beta)^2+\frac{4\alpha\gamma}{d-1}}}{2}\\
\end{align}
and it is up to you to find an asymptotic bound for it.

Comment: After computation from your expression, an interesting lower bound then turns out to be $1 - \frac{\alpha + \gamma}{d-1}$. The steps are clear to me except how you determine the rank of $K$. If I manage to express a matrix using a sum of products of $k$ vectors, I get a $k$-rank matrix ? Does this arise directly from the definition of the rank ?

Comment: @ippiki-ookami I should write "rank $\le2$" instead. Of course, the rank of the sum of $k$ rank-1 matrices is at most $k$, but strict inequality may hold.